# Element wise multiplication but only select columns

Tags: r

I have a large data frame in which I am wanting to do element-wise multiplication but only for some columns. Here is an example of the DF

```
 Name   Age State Student_A  Student_B  Height_Student_A Height_Student_B 
   A     2   NZ    0.5         NA          0.5                0.2     
   B     1   AS    0.5         NA          0.5                0.2     
   C     4   MU    NA         0.6          0.5                0.2     
   D     5   BY    NA         0.7          0.5                0.2
```

The goal is to multiple each student by the matching Height column. The Output should look something like

```
 Name   Age State Student_A  Student_B  Height_Student_A Height_Student_B Score_Student_A Score_Student B 
   A     2   NZ    0.5         NA          0.5                0.2           0.25           NA     
   B     1   AS    0.5         NA          0.5                0.2           0.25           NA
   C     4   MU    NA         0.6          0.5                0.2           NA             0.12
   D     5   BY    NA         0.7          0.5                0.2           NA             0.14
```

My suspicion is to use element wise multiplication but I wasn't sure how to specify which columns to begin with. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture Student columns and Height columns and multiply them directly.

```
student_cols <- sort(grep('^Student', names(df), value = TRUE))
height_cols <- sort(grep('^Height', names(df), value = TRUE))
df[paste0('Score_', student_cols)] <- df[student_cols] * df[height_cols]
df

#  Name Age State Student_A Student_B Height_Student_A Height_Student_B Score_Student_A Score_Student_B
#1    A   2    NZ       0.5        NA              0.5              0.2            0.25              NA
#2    B   1    AS       0.5        NA              0.5              0.2            0.25              NA
#3    C   4    MU        NA       0.6              0.5              0.2              NA            0.12
#4    D   5    BY        NA       0.7              0.5              0.2              NA            0.14
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game, but it might help you (and address [@latlio's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65694839/element-wise-multiplication-but-only-select-columns#comment116153095_65694942)) to generalize this for other handling as well (since Ronak's deals quite well as a general solution for this data).

Reshape it a bit. Unfortunately I'm not the strongest with `tidyr::pivot`s, so it's possible there's a better way to do this.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(dat, -c("Name", "Age", "State"), names_pattern = "(.*)_([^_]+)$", names_to = c("type", "AB")) %>%
  pivot_wider(c(Name:State, AB), names_from = "type", values_from = "value") %>%
  mutate(Score = Student * Height_Student)
# # A tibble: 8 x 7
#   Name    Age State AB    Student Height_Student  Score
#   <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>          <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 A         2 NZ    A         0.5            0.5  0.25 
# 2 A         2 NZ    B        NA              0.2 NA    
# 3 B         1 AS    A         0.5            0.5  0.25 
# 4 B         1 AS    B        NA              0.2 NA    
# 5 C         4 MU    A        NA              0.5 NA    
# 6 C         4 MU    B         0.6            0.2  0.12 
# 7 D         5 BY    A        NA              0.5 NA    
# 8 D         5 BY    B         0.7            0.2  0.140
```

Answer (score 0):

Since R is vectorized you can multiply the columns directly to create the new columns:

```
DF$Score_Student_A <- DF$Student_A * DF$Height_Student_A
DF$Score_Student_B <- DF$Student_B * DF$Height_Student_B
```

Comment: Do you have a generalized solution for this? What if you had 20 students? I'm guessing you wouldn't want to rewrite the code 20 times